# Defining a constant value at begining Haskell function

Tags: list, function, haskell, permutation

I have just started learning Haskell and have written two functions, one for lists with even lengths and one for lists odd lengths. This means the 'even' function with [0..7] returns [0,7,2,5,4,3,6,1], and the 'odd' function with [0..8] returns [0,7,2,5,4,3,6,1,8] - these are the results I need.
However I after a lot of work I am still not able to combine them so that just one function works for both lists. Here are the functions and I wondered if more experienced Haskell coders know of a solution.

```
funcOdd :: [Int] -> [Int]
funcOdd [] = []
funcOdd (x:xs) = take (n+1) ((x*2) : (pred n - x):funcOdd(xs))  where n = length xs

funcEven :: [Int] -> [Int]
funcEven [] = []
funcEven (x:xs) = take (n+1) ((x*2) : (n - x):funcEven(xs))  where n = length xs
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could explain the intended meaning and/or purpose of this function. This smells like it could be something mathematical. Thinking about the underlying meaning could lead to a simpler, cleaner solution than staring at code.

Answer (score 1):

You can pattern match to separate the cases

```
fullFunction theList | even (length theList) = funcEven theList
fullFunction theList = funcOdd theList
```

when you call `fullFunction`, it will try the first case, checking if the length of the list is even.  If this fails it will fallback to the second case.

Comment: Thanks for that, it did not occur to me that pattern matching could be used on functions.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps cleaner this way

```
func xs = zipWith const (go xs) xs
     where go [] = []
           go (x:xs) = 2*x : ((length xs)-off-x) : go xs
           off = mod (length xs) 2
```

the only difference I see between the two functions is use of `pred n` vs `n` which is replaced with off(set) derived from the length of the original list.

`zipWith const ...` truncates the result with the length of the original list to replace `take (n+1)`.

Comment: Thanks karakfa. I have used `zipWith const ... `  in a derivation of your function now but cannot work out how it works.  How does the `zipWith`  work in relation to the go function? Does `(go xs) xs`  act as a list?

Comment: it zips `(go xs)` with `xs` and picks the first element.  That's to limit the length of the list to min length of the two which is length of `xs` in this case.  fyi: `const a b = a`.  I think here you can use `take x` since length is already calculated.